# What does `($propertyname,)+[asc|desc]?` actually means?

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-mvc

There is Spring Data Rest [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) can somebody explain the sorting expression [`($propertyname,)+[asc|desc]?`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d5e118)? It looks like regular expression, but I doubt.

I understand that in case when I simply add `?sort=name` to query string Spring returns entities sorted by `name` with ascending order, but how to construct query string to get entities with descending order?

Answer (score 2):

[Yes, it's a regex.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#d0e812)† It means you can do have a comma-separated list of one or more properties, followed by an optional `asc` or `desc`. For example:

```
sort=firstname,lastname
sort=firstname,lastname,asc
sort=firstname,lastname,desc
sort=firstname,asc&sort=lastname,desc
```

† Okay, it's not an *actual* regex, but you get the idea. More correct (but still not a regex due to the expression-language `$`): `$propertyname(,$propertyname)*(,(asc|desc))?`

Comment: It is very complex to understand what do mean. Could you please edit your answer and delete unnessecary information?

Comment: No, the answer is complete. What part don't you understand? **edit** Okay, maybe you wanted a simple answer to "how to construct query string to get entities with descending order". This would be: `sort=name,desc`

Comment: "Yes, it's a regex.†" and after "† Okay, it's not an actual regex" Also symbol "†" confused me :)

Comment: "†" is a typographical symbol for a note, like an asterisk. What i meant was that their format doesn't follow actual regex syntax, but that you can treat it as a regex if that helps you understand what's going on.

Comment: Do you know which class is responsible of parsing these values and producing the `Sort` object from them?